# i sent post request of multipart/form-data to nextjs api and i want to send from this api to nodejs api. but files is encoded in nextjs api so not

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, next.js

i sent post request of multipart/form-data to nextjs api and i want to send from this api to nodejs api so as to not expose server api and also jwt token. but file is encoded in nextjs api so not working in server api and throwing too many parameters.

i tried to many ways but failed maybe because i am a beginner
t tried chatgpt, i tried some third party packages but i do not want to use any third party packages in nextjs api because i dont want to store image file there. i have a controller that does the work.

form.js

```
const CreateBlog = () => {
  const [form, setForm] = useState({});
  const [image, setImage] = useState();

  const formData = new FormData();
  formData.append('form', form);
  formData.append('image', image);

  //handle submit form
  const submitHandler = async (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
    try {
      if (!form.isDraft) form.isDraft = false;
      const response = await axios.post('/api/blogs/CreateBlog', formData, {
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      const data = await response.data;
      console.log('client: ', data);
    } catch (error) {
      console.log(error);
    }
    //console.log(image);
  };

  return (
    <div className={` ${Styles.wrap} `}>
      <form onSubmit={submitHandler} encType='multipart/form-data'>
```

handleform.js

```
import axios from 'axios';
import { getCookie } from 'cookies-next';

// Send a create blog POST request
export default async function createBlogHandler(req, res) {
  const token = getCookie('blogTubeUser', { req, res });

  const formData = req.body; // works

  if (req.method === 'POST') {
    try {
      const response = await axios.post(
        'http://localhost:5000/blogs',
        formData,
        {
          headers: {
            Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`,
          },
          withCredentials: true,
        }
      );

      res.status(200).json(response.data);
    } catch (error) {
      res.json(error.response.data);
    }
  } else {
    // handle unsupported method
    res.status(405).json({ message: 'some internal error' });
  }
}
```

from this api i want to send to node server where i have configured multer (it reaches the success part but file is missing. nextjs api is receving file form html but not sending to server

**if i am asking foolishly that is because i am a beginner and sorry for that. thank you so much**